# Ist die Schreibweise "Reflektion" falsch?

Tags: spelling

> Wenn eine Welle reflektiert wird, spricht man von Reflexion.

Ich finde die Schreibweise "Reflektion" hier intuitiver und *empfinde* die Schreibweise mit "x" als falsch (obwohl ich weiß, dass sie korrekt ist).

Aber, ist es falsch "Reflektion" anstatt "Reflexion" zu schreiben oder sind beide Schreibweisen erlaubt?

---

Edit: [NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Reflektion,Reflexion&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=8&smoothing=3) scheint nicht auf meiner Seite zu sein, allerdings zeigt sich ein winziger Anstieg seit der Jahrtausendwende.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die Verwirrung kommt wahrscheinlich daher, da wir gebräuchliche Wörter mit ähnlicher Bedeutung und augenscheinlich gleicher Herkunft mit ***'k'*** schreiben:

> *Reflektor*, *reflektieren*.

Da käme es sehr gelegen, wenn man auch die *Reflexion* mit 'k' schriebe. Aber es gibt schließlich noch den

> Reflex

Dieser wäre mit 'k' geschrieben eindeutig falsch: *Refleks*. Und das führt uns zur Etymologie dieser Wörter:

> **reflektieren**:  entlehnt (Anfang 17. Jh.) aus lat. *reflectere* (reflexum) ‘rückwärtsbiegen, zurückbeugen, drehen, wenden, umkehren’; vgl. lat. *flectere* ‘beugen, biegen, wenden, lenken’.<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=reflektieren)</sup>

und

> **Reflexion**: aus spätlat. *reflexio* (Gen. *reflexiōnis*) ‘das Zurückbeugen’ bzw. aus darauf beruhendem mfrz. frz. *réflexion*. Im Dt. auch (im Anschluß an den Infinitiv des Verbs) *Reflection* (17. Jh.) bzw. (vereinzelt bis ins 20. Jh.) *Reflektion*.<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Reflexion)</sup>

Das ***'x'*** stammt also ursprünglich aus dem Spätlateinischen, dem unsere *"Reflexion"* entlehnt ist. Somit wäre es nach heutiger Auffassung auch die "richtige" Schreibweise.

Interessant ist aber an obigem Zitat, dass das nicht immer so war, und dass wir noch heute in seriösen und redigierten Publikationen die Schreibweise mit 'k' finden:

> - Musik um der Musik willen hat mich nie interessiert", sagt Glatzel. "Kunst ist immer eine **Reflektion** über die ganze Gesellschaft."<sup>[Die Zeit 2009](http://www.zeit.de/online/2009/20/andromeda-mega-express)</sup>
> - Die Untersuchung ergab, dass der Satellit Kosmos 1382 eine starke **Reflektion** von Sonnenstrahlen auf einer Wolkenschicht als Startblitz von Interkontinentalraketen interpretiert hatte.<sup>[Die Zeit 2008](http://www.zeit.de/2008/39/A-Petrow)</sup>
> - Opel-Logo (mit **Reflektion** des Reichstags in Berlin): Trotz des relativ niedrigen Marktanteils musste Opel im Untersuchungszeitraum die meisten Fahrzeuge zurückrufen.<sup>[Spiegel 2009](http://www.spiegel.de/auto/aktuell/0,1518,644263,00.html)</sup>

Nun mag das ja der Aufmerksamkeit des Lektors entgangen sein; aber vielleicht erschien es diesem auch so, dass *Reflektion* nicht wirklich falsch wirkt. Dein Google ngram zeigt schließlich auch, dass das Wort zunehmend vorkommt.

Richtig richtig wird es aber erst, wenn es "offiziell" Eingang in die Wörterbücher gefunden hat und das ist heute noch nicht der Fall.

Comment: Sehr interessante Antwort, Danke. Mir scheint, dass das spätlat. *reflexio* (wo das "x" ja anscheinend herkommt) stark mit dem *reflectere* verwandt zu sein scheint, was für mich so aussieht, als sei es bereits von den Römern zu irgend einem Zeitpunkt "falsch" mit "x" statt mit "ct" geschrieben worden zu sein. Ist "Reflexion" also ein jahrtausendealter Rechtschreib-Folgefehler (Abschreibfehler)?

Comment: Jein: Im Lateinischen war es üblich, statt "cs" "x" zu schreiben. Dort war die Entwicklung also *reflecsio --> reflexio. So etwas erkennt man auch bei lateinischen Substantiven, die im Nominativ Singular auf -x enden, aber in flektierten Formen dieses x verlieren: Singular "Index", Plural "Indices" (lat.), "Indizes" (dt.).

Comment: Es ist (schon im antiken Latein) völlig regelmäßig, daß Verben mit Präsensstamm auf _-t_ oder _-d_ den Supinstamm bilden, indem dieser Dental durch _s_ ersetzt wird: _mittere/missus_, _cadere/casus_ und eben auch _flectere/flexus_ (statt _flecsus_, wie @elena schon erläutert hat). Vom Supinstamm können dann Substantive mit _-or_ und _-io_ abgeleitet werden, z.B _missio_, _actio_, _doctor_. Es müßte also eigentlich auch _Reflexor_ heißen; wer das Wort _Reflektor_ gebildet hat, kannte die lat. Wortbildungsregeln offenkundig nicht mehr.

Comment: Die Wiktionary-Autoren haben auch kein Problem damit, die Existenz von [Reflektion](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reflektion) anzuerkennen.

Answer (score -1):

Somit haben wir hier also ein Problem der Inkonsequenz. Richtiger wäre, wie chirlu sagte, Reflexor im Lateinischen und natürlich, wenn wir Reflektor im Deutschen sagen, wäre in unserer Sprache Reflektion richtiger (zumal, was man vielleicht mitbedenken sollte, wir die Reflexion normalerweise nicht "refleksion", sondern "reflektion" aussprechen).

Bin mal gespannt, ob ich es noch erlebe, dass sich diese meines Empfindens stumpfsinnige Regelung überlebt und sich die deutsche Sprache endlich für die deutsche oder lateinische Aussprache (und Schreibweise) entscheidet, statt aus historischen Gründen beide zu vermischen, sodass einem ständig das eigene Sprachempfinden in die Quere kommt.

Comment: Wilkommen auf German Language SE. Leider ist Deine Antwort wegen ihrer vielen Bezüge schwer verständlich und beantwortet die eigentliche Frage, nämlich was richtig sei, auch nicht wirklich. Außerdem der Ausspracheunterschied (wenn man analog zu anderen Wörtern vorgeht) zwischen *Reflexion* und *Reflektion* minimal: [ʀeflɛksi̯oːn] vs. [ʀeflɛkʦi̯oːn] (vgl. mit Nation, das [naʦi̯oːn] ausgesprochen wird.