# Reflektanz und Reflexion

Tags: spelling, semantics

Ich schreibe gerade eine Arbeit über das Reflektanzverhalten verschiedener Materialien. Ich meine damit die Art und Weise wie gewisse Oberflächen eintreffende Elektromagnetische Wellen in eine andere Richtung zurückwerfen.

Ich bin mir allerdings trotz Recherche immer noch nicht sicher wie ich Wörter rund um das Thema Reflexion schreiben muss.

[Dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/ist-die-schreibweise-reflektion-falsch/3814#3814) habe ich entnommen, dass im Grunde gilt:

- *Reflexion* richtig
- *Reflektion* falsch
- *reflektieren* richtig
- *reflexieren* falsch

Wie steht es aber mit dem Wort Reflektanz? Gibt es das Wort und wenn ja welchen Bedeutungsunterschied gibt es zu Reflexion? Ich selbst benutze es etwa im Sinne von *Reflexionseigenschaften* oder *[Reflexionsgrad](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexionsgrad)*. Allerdings gibt bei duden.de dazu nicht mal einen Treffer.

#### Ein paar Beispiel Auszüge aus meinem Text:

- > Das Reflektanzverhalten eines Materials …
  > Das Reflexionsverhalten eines Materials …
- > Die Reflektanz ist außerordentlich, da …
  > Die Reflexion ist außerordentlich, da …
- > Approximierung eines Reflektanzmodells …
  > Approximierung eines Reflexionsmodells …

Ich hoffe mir kann jemand das Ganze etwas entwirren.

Comment: Ich würde "Reflektanz" als "Sachverhalt/Naturerscheinung" handhaben und "Reflexion" als "Aktion". Also am Beispiel deiner Auszüge: "Die Reflektanz eines Materials ..." und "Das Reflexionsverhalten eines Materials" / "Die Reflexion ist außerordentlich, da ..." / "Approximierung eines Reflektanzmodells"

Comment: Danke für den Kommentar. Das würde mir schon mal helfen in der Entwirrung. Hast du vielleicht einen Link dazu? Ich finde es nämlich etwas komisch, dass es weder bei duden.de noch bei wiktionary einen Eintrag zu _Reflektanz_ gibt.

Comment: Der [Wikipediaeintrag: Reflexionsgrad](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexionsgrad) nennt "Reflektanz" immerhin - neben "Reflexionsvermögen" und "Reflektivität" - als Synonym.

Comment: Von diesen vier Synonymen hat der der Duden immhin einen Eintrag für [Reflexionsgrad](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Reflexionsgrad). In meinem österreichischen Wörterbuch wird keines der Wörter erwähnt. Wörterbücher führen im Allgemeinen keine umfassende Liste aller existierenden Wörter, das wäre auch gar nicht möglich. Besonders bei Fachbegriffen gibt es oft konkurierende Wörter, nicht selten mit mehr oder weniger subtilen Bedeutungsunterschieden (hier dürften es tatsächlich Synonyme sein). Die besten Anhaltspunkte bietet hier wohl die von dir als Referenz verwendete Literatur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Richtig ist (wie du schon erkannt hast):

> Reflexion / reflektieren

Das Wort Reflektanz findet sich nicht im Duden. Es wird in der Physik gelegentlich verwendet, wenn man den Reflexionsgrad beschreiben will. Gängiger wäre hier aber die Verwendung von Reflexionsgrad. Reflektanz ist ein gelegentlich verwendeter Anglizismus in Anlehnung an das englische Wort *reflectance*, was übersetzt *Reflexionsgrad* oder eben auch *Reflektanz* bedeutet.
Inhaltlich sind also Reflexion und Reflektanz/Reflexionsgrad nicht das selbe. *Reflektanzverhalten* habe ich in physikalischer Literatur noch nie gesehen.